# How to run a PowerShell Script in the background (no window) from Windows Explorer?

Tags: powershell, shell, scripting, explorer

I'm trying to run a PowerShell script from Windows Explorer, i.e. not from a command line window. The script is supposed to run seamlessly in the background, without any window opening up.

I have tried using a shortcut in the Explorer with this command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -File "...\Script.ps1"
```

But still a CMD window flashes on the screen for a moment. How can I run a script from Windows Explorer, truly without any window opening up?

Best regards and thanks for your help,
theCoffeeProject

Comment: Yes, thank you! Still the solution might contribute to my second problem: The delay until the first line of my script is actually executed.

Comment: The delay could possibly be reduced by launching PowerShell from a native executable that calls `CreateProcess`, passing the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag.

Comment: In this case the part using VBS wouldn't be neccesarry anymore? I don't know how to create a native executable on Windows. Could you help me with some website that describes a simple way to achieve that?

Comment: Correct. No need for VBS if you have a native launcher. Something like this should already exist, if you can't find one maybe ask on SuperUser.